# Why can't I increase my <p> size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Despite adding an ID my font-size isn't changing for the paragraph 'Popular Articles'?

If you use Google Webmaster Tools, it appears the ID hasn't been set-up, yet if you look at my stylesheet you can see it (line 468). Why isn't it working?

**Live Link:** http://185.123.97.138/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/blog.html

**HTML:** (Line 143)

```
<div style="margin-top: 30px;" class="popular-articles">
<p class="popular-articles">Popular articles</p> 
</div>
```

**CSS** (See line 468 at - http://185.123.97.138/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/css/homepagestyle.css)

```
.popular-articles {
margin-top: 30px;
    font-size: 110%;
}
```

Comment: Changed Id's to Classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it isn't working because the ID of the `p` is the same as your `div`. Change your `p` to a `div class` like `<p class="popular-article-text">`. Then you must be able to change the font size of the `#popular-article` div or the `p` class.

You should never use the same class or id for different kind of elements.

HTML

```
<div style="margin-top: 30px;" id="popular-articles">
<p class="popular-articles-text">Popular articles</p> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
#popular-articles {
margin-top: 30px;
}

.popular-articles-text {
font-size: 110%;
}
```

Comment: Good point, but doesn't make a difference most modern browsers don't care if you use an ID multiple times. I've since changed it to a class and it's still not showing?

Comment: Tried to change your div to a id, and your p to a class? @SamJefferies

Comment: @SamJefferies There is a difference between a `class` and a `id` and its selector for css `.` and `#`. You can use id multiple times for example a container but its not recommend to use the same id for other kinds of elements like a `p` and a `div` and that goes the same for a `class`!

Answer (score 1):

You put two }} on the line 465 & 466. Remove any one }.

Also there is : instead of ; on the line 354 & 360.
it should be like this

```
text-align: center;
```

Comment: Thanks Maulik! Good eye!

Answer (score 0):

You can not put same id for more than one element.

Instead you could use same class for both the div and p tag.

The above code should be like this :

**HTML**

```
<div class="popular-articles">
  <p class="popular-articles">Popular articles</p> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.popular-articles {
    margin-top: 30px;
      font-size: 110%;
}
```

Comment: Good point, but doesn't make a difference most modern browsers don't care if you use an ID multiple times. I've since changed it to a class and it's still not showing?